# My server keeps changing xss-protection 1 to 0

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, xss

I am using .htaccess to add some security headers for my website. But it keep changing it back to `X-XSS-Protection: 0` am I missing a server config? I am running apache.

Inside .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

HTTP Response Header:

[image: 1]

Comment: is there another component in front of your webserver that might keep changing this? Perhaps nginx proxy or cloud provider's infrastructure?

Comment: @JurajMartinka Hey, I have Cloudflare. I wouldn't think cloudflare is changing it...